# firestore получить коллекцию из документа

Tags: firebase, firestore

Добрый день! Прошу подсказать, как получить субколлекции (читай, коллекции из документа) из обращения к основному экземпляру базы данных FireStore.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

Например, есть структура FireStore (коллекции):

db.collection("cities").document("SF").collection("basic")

db.collection("cities").document("SF").collection("other")

Можно ли из документа (document("SF")) получить все коллекции. Или же это невозможно? В документации ничего такого не нашел, хотя сам интерфейс по работе с данными Firestore позволяет видеть эти коллекции(добавлять и удалять данные), а из кода не нашел обращения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошел год, но все же, сам искал ответ на этот вопрос. Нашел ответ - нельзя.
[документация, смотри в самом низу](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)
Вот так написанно:
"Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable."